# PHP PDO Connect to Sybase

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have been spending too much time without any success on connecting to Sybase database using PDO. I found lot of threads on MS SQL but very less on Sybase. I am using PHP Version 5.6.14 on Windows 10 in my laptop.

From the dblib [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php), it is stated that "This extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later." (I used dblib in Ubuntu server). So I tried using another drivers which are "SqlSrv" and also "ODBC", both of them with no success still. From my PhpInfo(), list of PDO drivers available is **mysql, odbc, pgsql, sqlite, sqlsrv**.

**SQLSRV**

I have followed this [link](http://craigballinger.com/blog/2011/08/usin-php-5-3-with-mssql-pdo-on-windows/) step by step and install appropriate version. However connection string below

```
$dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=xx.xx.xx.xx,PORTNUMBER;Database=MYDBNAME", "MYUSERNAME", "MYPASSWORD");
```

returned the error *SQLSTATE[HY000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Protocol error in TDS stream*

**ODBC**

As for the ODBC, I have tried using below connection string

```
$dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver=SQL Server;Server=xx.xx.xx.xx;Port:PORTNUMBER;Database=MYDBNAME", "MYUSERNAME", "MYPASSWORD");
```

returned error of *SQLSTATE[08001] SQLDriverConnect: 17 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.*

So I have no idea at all now on the next step that I can take. I really appreciate some guidance or useful links for me to go through. Thanks.